# Обработка ошибок в RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript-типы

Не могу получить доступ к данным об ошибке в RTK Query. В [документации](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) четко показано, что объект ошибки, который достается из генерируемого хука мутации имеет поле `data`.

На деле же объект имеет юнион тип `FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError | undefined`. И при попытке получить доступ к полю `data` typescript говорит о том, что такого поля не существует.

Пытался даже использовать метод `transformErrorResponse` внутри функции `createApi`. Но, при попытке задать свою структуру объекта, возникает множество конфликтов с типизацией, в результате чего изменению поддается только поле `status`.

#### api.ts

```
 export const authApi = createApi({
   reducerPath: "api/auth",
   baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/auth` }),
   endpoints: (builder) => ({
      login: builder.mutation<ResponseBody, RequestBody>({
           query: (body) => ({
                url: 'login',
                method: "POST",
                body
           })
      }),

      register: builder.mutation<ResponseBody, RequestBody>({
           query: (body) => ({
                url: 'registration',
                method: "POST",
                body,
           }),
           async onQueryStarted(queryBody, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                try {
                     const { data } = await queryFulfilled
                     const user = decodeToken(data.token)
                     dispatch(authorizeUser(user))
                } catch (err) {
                     console.error(err)
                }
           },
      })
 })
```

#### component.tsx

```
export const RegistrationBody: React.FC = () => {

// ... //

const [register, { error, isError, data }] = useRegisterMutation()

const submit = async (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    await register({ email, password })
}

// ... //

if (isError && error) console.log(error.data)

return (
    // ... //
)
```

}

В компоненте, при попытке получить доступ к полю `data`, получаю ошибку

Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError'. Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SerializedError'.

Answer (score 0):

Также сталкивался примерно с похожей проблемой.

**Здесь вижу два возможных варианты решения**:

1. При использовании fetchBaseQuery свойство error, возвращаемое из перехватчика, будет иметь тип Ошибка базового запроса FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError | undefined. Если ошибка присутствует, вы можете получить доступ к свойствам ошибки, сузив тип либо до FetchBaseQueryError, либо до SerializedError.

Собственно *сузить тип* можно с помощью следующих функций:

### services/helpers.ts

```ts
import { FetchBaseQueryError } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

export function isFetchBaseQueryError(error: unknown): error is FetchBaseQueryError {
  return typeof error === 'object' && error != null && 'status' in error
}

export function isErrorWithMessage(
  error: unknown,
): error is { message: string } {
  return (
    typeof error === 'object' &&
    error != null &&
    'message' in error &&
    typeof (error as any).message === 'string'
  )
}
```

### addPost.tsx

```ts
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'
import { api } from './services/api'
import { isFetchBaseQueryError, isErrorWithMessage } from './services/helpers'

function AddPost() {
  const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [addPost] = useAddPostMutation()

  async function handleAddPost() {
    try {
      await addPost(name).unwrap()
      setName('')
    } catch (err) {
      if (isFetchBaseQueryError(err)) {
        // you can access all properties of `FetchBaseQueryError` here
        const errMsg = 'error' in err ? err.error : JSON.stringify(err.data)
        enqueueSnackbar(errMsg, { variant: 'error' })
      } else if (isErrorWithMessage(err)) {
        // you can access a string 'message' property here
        enqueueSnackbar(err.message, { variant: 'error' })
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button>Add post</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Весь код взят из документации по RTK Query:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#error-result-example

2. Написать свою кастомную ошибку с использованием своей функции для обращения к серверу ****queryFn****, вместо стандартного **query**.
   Ссылка на документацию: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#type-safe-error-handling и https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-a-queryfn